# What is the range for PTRACE_TRACEME?

Tags: c++, linux, ptrace

If I have a code like this:

```
void child() {
    do_something();
    ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0);
    do_some_other_things();
}
```

then will `do_something()` be traced by the parent?

I found in the linux documentation, there were not such thing. It only said this should be called in the tracee.

> PTRACE_TRACEME
>
> Indicate that this process is to be traced by its parent.  A
> process probably shouldn't make this request if its parent
> isn't expecting to trace it.  (pid, addr, and data are
> ignored.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [How Debuggers Work Part 1](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/01/23/how-debuggers-work-part-1) for a better explanation, but in summary, no, it will not trace the do_something() function until the tracee receives a signal.

In the description of the *ptrace* call from that same **man ptrace** you quoted:

> A  process  can  initiate  a  trace  by  calling  fork(2)  and having
>   the resulting child do a
>   PTRACE_TRACEME, followed (typically) by an execve(2).  Alternatively, one process may commence
>   tracing another process using PTRACE_ATTACH or PTRACE_SEIZE.
>
> While  being  traced, the tracee will stop each time a signal is delivered, even if the signal
>          is being ignored.  (An exception is SIGKILL, which has its usual effect.)  The tracer will  be
>          notified at its next call to waitpid(2) (or one of the related "wait" system calls); that call
>          will return a status value containing information that indicates the cause of the stop in  the
>          tracee.

When the tracee calls exec, it receives a signal, that's why it stops.

To illustrace, tracer program mainer.c with no bells or whistles:

```
//mainer.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
        pid_t child_pid;
        char * programname = argv[1];

        child_pid = fork();
        if (child_pid == 0)
        {
                ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0);
                execl(programname, programname, NULL);
        }

        else if (child_pid > 0) 
        {
            int status;

            wait(&status);

            while (WIFSTOPPED(status))
            {
                    struct user_regs_struct regs;
                    ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child_pid, 0, &regs);
                    unsigned instr = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, child_pid, regs.eip, 0);
                    printf("EIP = 0x%08x, instr = 0x%08x\n", regs.eip, instr);

                    ptrace(PTRACE_SINGLESTEP, child_pid, 0, 0);

                    wait(&status);
            }

        }
}
```

When the tracee hits exec, it will receive a signal and pass control to the parent, who is waiting.
Assembly program to trace, there's just way too much going on when tracing a C program to extract anything useful:

```
; hello.asm
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov edx,len1
    mov ecx,hello1
    mov ebx,1
    mov eax,4

    int 0x80


    mov edx,len2
    mov ecx,hello2
    mov ebx,1
    mov eax,4

    int 0x80

    mov eax,1
    int 0x80

section .data
    hello1 db "Hello",0xA
    len1 equ $ - hello1

    hello2 db "World",0xA
    len2 equ $ - hello2
```

Running this, `./mainer hello`

```
EIP = 0x08048080, instr = 0x00000000
EIP = 0x08048085, instr = 0x00000000
EIP = 0x0804808a, instr = 0x00000000
EIP = 0x0804808f, instr = 0x00000000
EIP = 0x08048094, instr = 0x00000000
Hello
EIP = 0x08048096, instr = 0x00000000
EIP = 0x0804809b, instr = 0x00000000
EIP = 0x080480a0, instr = 0x00000000
EIP = 0x080480a5, instr = 0x00000000
EIP = 0x080480aa, instr = 0x00000000
World
EIP = 0x080480ac, instr = 0x00000000
EIP = 0x080480b1, instr = 0x00000000
```

If we modify mainer.c so the child process calls do_something() before it's exec the result of the trace is the exact same. This is just how I modified it, you can confirm yourself if you like that the results are the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int do_something(void)        //added this function
{
        printf("Doing something");
        return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
        pid_t child_pid;
        char * programname = argv[1];

        child_pid = fork();
        if (child_pid == 0)
        {
                ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0);
                do_something();      //added this function call
                execl(programname, programname, NULL);
        }

        else if (child_pid > 0) 
        {
            int status;

            wait(&status);

            while (WIFSTOPPED(status))
            {
                    struct user_regs_struct regs;
                    ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child_pid, 0, &regs);
                    unsigned instr = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, child_pid, regs.eip, 0);
                    printf("EIP = 0x%08x, instr = 0x%08x\n", regs.eip, instr);

                    ptrace(PTRACE_SINGLESTEP, child_pid, 0, 0);

                    wait(&status);
            }

        }
}
```

So the tracee won't stop until it receives a signal, which is what happens when it calls exec, and calling functions doesn't generate a signal for the tracee, but there are other ways to send a signal to the tracee and begin tracing, although they are not as tidy as exec and wait.